# Javascript reduce - split accumulator in multiple variables

Tags: javascript, reduce

Why `t` becomes `undefined` in second iteration?

```js
function findShortest(s){
 const arr = s.split(' ');
  
 arr.reduce(([acc, t], curr, idx) => {
  console.log('t', t)

  if (curr.length < t.length) {
      // some code
      t = curr;
    } else { 
      // some code
    }
    return acc;
  }, [[], '']);
  
  return arr;
  
}

console.log(findShortest('how are you doing this wonderfull coding man'));
```

I try to filter shortest words from array in one iteration so I dont need to loop array to get shortest word and then again, to filter it. You can see what was my first try. I end up with this:

```js
 const arr = s.split(' ');
  
 let shortest = 50;
  
 return arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
   if (curr.length < shortest) {
     acc = [];
      acc.push(curr);
      shortest = curr.length;
    } else if (curr.length === shortest) {
       acc.push(curr);
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);
```

But why in first approach `t` gets undefined?

Comment: Because you only return acc

Comment: Not returning all of the original start array ... try `return [acc, t];`. Unfortunate name of variable `acc` when it is only part of the original accumulator

Comment: To add a bit to other comments, whatever you return will be the next accumulator. Since your first `acc` variable is an empty array, your next acc will be an empty array that you will try to destructure into `[acc, t]`, so you will get undefined for both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take an array as result set and check against the length of the first collected string. At start check if the accumulator exists.

```js
function findShortest(s) {
   return s
       .split(' ')
       .reduce((acc, curr) => {
           if (!acc || curr.length < acc[0].length) {
               return [curr];
           }
           if (curr.length === acc[0].length) {
               acc.push(curr);
           }
           return acc;
       }, undefined);
}

console.log(findShortest('how are you doing this wonderfull coding man'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Approach reducing to object where keys are lengths and values are arrays of same length words.

```js
function findShortest(s) {
  const wordsObj = s
    .split(' ')
    .reduce((acc, curr) => {
      const len = curr.trim().length;
      if (len) {       
        acc[len] = (acc[len] || []).concat(curr);      
      }
      return acc;
    }, {});

  return wordsObj[Math.min(...Object.keys(wordsObj))]
}

console.log(findShortest('how are you doing this wonderfull coding man'));
```